# Add SDT PSI/SI information in a TS file

Tags: mux, dvb

Is there any software that can add SDT information on a already muxed ts file ? I can remux the mpeg file to TS again but I just can't find anything that guides me on how to add the sdt tables, all I can find are the DVB analyser and they cannot add a sdt table into the ts file or even mux it with the tables. Maybe my google-fu is rusted... Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It is called OpenCaster. One of its tools does the trick.

Comment: Hi, Is openCaster a good choice compared to ffmpeg ? It seems that ffmpeg is more popular.